# Javascript / React - best way to not repeat myself

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on this back button for a when a query is made but i keep repeating myself with if statements every time there is more queries in the url. The '(([query, value]' is needed and i have to add another if statement if there is more.

```
 let url= Object.entries(searchQuery).map(([query, value])=>{
            return `${query.toString()}=${value.toString()}`;
    }); 

    }

    if (url.length === 2){
        return `/search?${url[0]}&${url[1]}`;
    }

    if (url.length === 3){
        return `/search?${url[0]}&${url[1]}&${url[2]}`;
    }
```

Comment: Just use a regular switch case statement

Comment: just create a function which creates the `/search?${url[0]}&${url[1]}` from the length and use it where you need it.

Comment: you could also potentially build the string you're returning by concatenating via a for loop and then just return the final string only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `.join('&')` your `url` array:

```
function createUrl(searchQuery) {
  let url = Object.entries(searchQuery).map(([query, value]) => {
    return `${query.toString()}=${value.toString()}`;
  });

  return `/search?${url.join('&')}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
let param = '';
for(let i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
    param += `${url[i]}&`
}

return "/search?" + param.slice(0, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `for` statement?

```
let retString = '/search?';
for(idx = 0; idx < url.length; idx++)
{
     retString += `&${url[idx]}`;
}
```